# What the hms resource values-zz and how delete this?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I cant update my app in Play Store because I get a message: The following unknown languages are configured for your App Bundle: zz
[image]

Comment: Are you using facebook login?

Comment: `defaultConfig { resConfigs "en" }` add this in build.gradle

Comment: no, i use hms-agconnect and hms-location

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

This problem is a known bug and it has been rectified already. Try to update the SDK to the latest version will also solve this issue.

---

You can go to the application's build.gradle file, which is in android->defaultConfig.
Then choose the languages using resConfigs

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        resConfigs "en", "fr"  //pick the languages you'd like to use
    }
}
```

Then rebuild the .aab file and try uploading.